# keycloak - microsoft azure ad security flaw

Tags: azure-active-directory, keycloak

Keycloak provides in-build functionality to integrate with different applications such as Microsoft Azure AD. I found an article talking about the security flaw in Azure ad. What types of configurations can be done in Keycloak to handle such security flaws? Any suggestions?

https://thehackernews.com/2023/06/critical-noauth-flaw-in-microsoft-azure.html

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: you're writing your own app. when a client wants to log in to your app, your app redirects the client to Keycloak, which is using MS as an identity provider, so the client logs in on an MS login page. Keycloak then redirects the client back to your app, and your app now knows whether the client's login was successful (ie. the client was authenticated).

Correct?

You now have to decide whether to *authorise* the client to access some resource in your app. How do you do that? You know that the client is *authenticated* at Microsoft, but you don't know if the client is *authorised* to access *your* resources.

You do this by examining the access token that your app got back from Keycloak. The access token contains, among other things, the email address that Microsoft associates with this user. The problem is that this address may be incorrect, so you must not use this email address to decide that the client can access your resources.

It's not a big deal. You shouldn't be using an email address for authorisation anyway. MS explains this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/claims-validation#validate-the-subject) under 'Claims validation'. Note:

> Never use claims like email, preferred_username or unique_name to
> store or determine whether the user in an access token should have
> access to data. These claims are not unique and can be controllable by
> tenant administrators or sometimes users, which makes them unsuitable
> for authorization decisions. They are only usable for display
> purposes.